# TRIM replaces LTRIM/RTRIM

Tags: java, sql, spring, oracle, jpa

I am fairly new to Oracle.

Is it safe to say that `LTRIM(RTRIM(<myVarchar>))` is totally replaceable by `TRIM(<myVarchar>)` if I want to replace both leading and trailing whitespaces in Oracle 11g?

Also, when I am trying to use this function in my query using JPA, I am getting error "org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node".

Here is the query that I am using:

```
@Query("Select p from OldPin p WHERE TRIM(p.eeNo) = :accNum and 
TRIM(p.pinStatus) = 'A' and TRIM(p.memberType='E') and TRIM(p.sCode) in 
('MSHK','MCMG')")
    public OldPin findByAccountNum(@Param("accNum") String accNum);
```

Comment: Yes, that's safe to say. I consider `LTRIM(RTRIM(<myVarchar>))` bad coding style

Comment: Being picky, but.... what do you mean by 'whitepace' - just spaces, or other things like tabs and newlines and non-breaking spaces? Your example defaults to just actual spaces, so they are equivalent; but that isn't always the case (i.e. when trimming a *set* of characters, not just one)..

Comment: Why do you have `='E'` inside a trim call - is that just a typo, for `and TRIM(p.memberType)='E'`?

Comment: I think it is safe to say that storing the strings with leading and trailing white space is generally a bad practice, unless these are intended as part of the value.  You should probably fix the data rather than the queries.

Comment: Errm, you're using JPQL, and there is no RTRIM / LTRIM in JPQL. Read a JPQL reference doc. If you mean SQL then you need "nativeQuery" in that thing

Comment: Thanks Billy! Using only TRIM() (and not LTRIM/RTRIM) worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trim will remove both leading and trailing spaces by default 
eg. Trim('     test      ') output will be test

If we use Trim(both  from ) then it will remove a character from both side 
eg., 
Trim(both '1' from '111oracle111') output will be oracle
Trim(leading '1' from '111oracle111') output will be oracle111
Trim(trailing '1' from '111oracle111') output will be 111oracle

Trim(both 'ab' from 'abtechab') - it will throw error, because trim will support single character only

In RTrim and LTrim we can remove any number of character.

Answer (score 1):

Too, you can use

```
select '%'||replace(' hello world ', ' ' , '')||'%' from dual;
```

and the output is

```
%helloworld%
```